# How to match regex with end of line?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that does the following:
- look for at least one `=`, and take these `=`  up to either 1) end of line, or 2) a dot `.`

The regex:

`[=]+?[=]+.*?[.$]+`

Teststrings:

```
b == 123 //does not match, but which should as it is end of line!
b == 123. //does match "== 123.", which is OK
b == 123.abc //does match "== 123.", which is OK
```

What am I missing here with the endofline `$` anchor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[.$]` means a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) consisting of a dot or a dollar sign. If you want alternatives between regex elements [you should use `|`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), i.e. `(\.|$)`.

Also, you could use [negative character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^…]` instead of [lazy matching](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) `…*?`:

```
([^=]+)=+([^.]+)(?:\.|$)
```